# opencl vector of image buffer/huge amount of data for image buffer

Tags: textures, opencl

I'm quite new to openCL and face a little problem with my current program.
I want to move a large amount of images on my device and I only need to read from them in my program. 
My problem is, that my device only lets me allocate buffers of ca. 255mb, 
Since the program should be able to handle different parameters and should also be able to run on several machines, I do not know the exact number of images I can put on the device beforehand but have to evaluate that at runtime.

To do so I would like to do something like creating several image buffers (textures) with my images stored in it and have another buffer which just contains pointers to these buffers.

Unfortunately I can't find any information on how I could to something like that (especially since image buffers always need to be declared either read_only or write_only) or if it is possible at all.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL does not allow pointers to images (or pointers to buffers).  An alternative would be to use a 3D texture if available.  OpenCL 1.2 also has separate objects for arrays of 2D textures (no interpolation along z-axis).  If you restrict yourself to 2D textures, you can still put several images into the same texture at different offsets.  Finally, you can generate your kernel code at runtime, allowing you to change the number of images passed as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already putting several images into the same texture, but unfortunately the memory (and the max_width/height) are limiting me. I suppose 3D textures won't solve the memory problem, but it could solve the width/height restriction, I will look into that.
I will most likely have to generate or at least alter the kernel code at runtime, but I had hoped I could avoid that, since "auto generated" code is harder to present later.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data as buffers then copy the input into images as needed to keep max images in texture memory using clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage

As for read and write on images you are confusing read/write only qualifiers on the kernel arguments with the actual opencl image being read or write. for each kernel an image can be either read only or write only but the image itself can be both as long as you use two kernels.
So use CL_MEM_READ_WRITE when you create the image2d but have one kernel that is reading the image and one that is writing it but it is still the same image. Also it is often easier to just have an input and an output opencl image and then copy the buffer into the image and then out of it as needed regardless of how many you have.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't really clear enough with my read/write restrictions. I only need to read from the image, I write in a different buffer, which does not need to be an image. The problem with your solution, although tempting, is that it won't get me all the images on the device at the same time.
Since I need to call clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage from host code, I would need to start multiple kernels (which I might need to do anyways because I also exceed the global memory limit).